# Finding the centre point of the visible parts in the Autodesk Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Excuse the vagueness of this question, but in a model in the viewer, I'd like to know how I can establish the centre point of the visible parts.  When I call fit-to-view on a model with hidden parts, I can see a dot appear in the viewer which seems to represent exactly this - the centre of the visible parts - how can I retrieve the coordinates of this point in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The little green dot represents the "target" of the camera. You can get its coordinates using `viewer.navigation.getTarget()`.